# Photo upload fails with Curl exception#26

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, photo-upload

Hello,

I am trying to upload photo to facebook through my facebook app.

Here is my code:

```
$photo_details = array(
        'message'=> 'my photo'
    );
$file = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/81/Waves_lajolla.jpg/300px-Waves_lajolla.jpg";  
$photo_details['image'] = '@'.realpath($file);

try {
    $upload_photo = $facebook->api('/'.'almbumId'.'/photos', 'post', $photo_details);
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo 'Error'.$e;
    error_log($e);
}
```

but it always gives me

> CurlException: 26: failed creating formpost data

Comment: Is your server successfully downloading that file? try with a local file first and see if that works

Comment: I tried with my local file too. but it throws the same Exception.. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your image path can't be an URL, it has to be local. For example:

```
$file='images/logo.jpg'; //Example image file
```

But did you get any solution on how to post image from an URL by any chance? If so please share as I'm looking to find a solution to post the image from an URL too.